# Nav Shrink on Scroll or Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to apply a series of classes to a `nav` that cause it to shrink if the  `window` is either resized or scrolled passed a certain point. However, I believe my conditions are cancelling each other out, and I'm not sure how to structure the `if-statements` or if it is better to just pass a variable.

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:

1. If the window is resized between a certain set of media queries, shrink the nav
2. If the window is outside of those break-points, and the user scrolls passed 1 (I used one just for example purposes in my code so I could see it right away) the `nav` will shrink and if they scroll up again, it will become it's full size

My code is here:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var logo = $('.logo');
var topLevelListItems = $('.mainNav li');
var navShrink = false;
var mQ = window.matchMedia( '(min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 770px)' );


$(window).resize(function() {

    if ( mQ.matches ) {
        $('nav').addClass('shrink');
        $('.nav-fixedWidth').addClass('shrink');
        logo.addClass('shrink');
        topLevelListItems.addClass('shrink');
        navShrink = true;
    }
    else{        
        $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
        $('.nav-fixedWidth').removeClass('shrink');
        logo.removeClass('shrink');
        topLevelListItems.removeClass('shrink');
        navShrink = false;
    }
});//end of resize function



$(window).onscroll(function(){
    if( !(mQ.match) && $(this).scrollTop >= 1 ) {
        $('nav').addClass('shrink');
        $('.nav-fixedWidth').addClass('shrink');
        logo.addClass('shrink');
        topLevelListItems.addClass('shrink');
        navShrink = true;
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
        $('.nav-fixedWidth').removeClass('shrink');
        logo.removeClass('shrink');
        topLevelListItems.removeClass('shrink');
        navShrink = false;
    }

});//end of scroll function
```

});//end of doc

Comment: Need to understand that both of those events trigger at high rate ie once per pixel. Also should be `$(window).on('scroll',function(){`

Comment: Read up on throttling and debounce techniques to prevent excessive dom manipulation

Comment: What object are you getting back from '$(this)' ? Window object has not a 'scrollTop' property instead of you can use 'pageYOffset' or 'scrollY'. Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: @charlietfl Hi, I explained that in the question.  I did it just to test out the scroll

Answer (score 0):

Could it simply be a typo in your onscroll function?

i.e you have:

`if( !(mQ.match) && $(this).scrollTop >= 1 ) { ...`

should it not be:

`if( !(mQ.matches) && $(this).scrollTop >= 1 ) { ...`